Error Kuberneter cluster after master node reboot
I restarted my kubernetes master node and after this, when I execute the get nodes command, it shows the worker node with NotReady state.
What should I do to prevent this from happening after each reboot of the master node?

There are 4 available statuses of the node in Kubernetes.

Ready means that node is healthy and ready to run pods
SchedulingDisabled means that node is not available to accept new
pods
NotReady means that node is unhealthy and unable to run pods
Unknown means that node is unavailable

So you can't prevent node from NotReady status in future. There are several steps to find out what's happened:
1. Check node resources
First of all you can login to the node by SSH and check node resources with commands top, free, uptime and ss. Or check it in monitoring dashboard if you have it.
2. Check conditions section
You can run kubectl describe node <node-name> and check conditions sections in the output.

MemoryPressure means that there is low memory on the node
DiskPressure means that there is low disk space on the node
PIDPressure means that there are too many processes on the node
NetworkUnavailable means that there are some network issues
Ready - this field can have True, False or Unknown values. If
value is Unknown - it means that node controller have no messages
from the node for node-monitor-grace-period (40 seconds by default)

3. Check K8s components
You can also connect to the node by SSH and check K8s components like kube-proxy, kubelet and docker (or containerd)
kubectl logs [pod name] -n kube-system
systemctl status kubelet
systemctl status docker/containerd
4. Finally you can check cluster events
kubectl get events —all-namespaces
